# In StackDriver logging viewer is there a way to query for entries that DO NOT contain a specific string

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

My question is wrt to the log viewer at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer All the examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer_v2?hl=en_US&_ga=2.101694786.-259888181.1479444123#searching_and_filtering_logs) show how to search for existence of text but not for absence.

I want to use this functionality to search for errors that do not contain "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Advanced Logs Filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters) which support the `NOT` boolean operator:

> Boolean expressions
>
> ```
> expression =
>     ["NOT" | "-"] comparison {["AND" | "OR"] ["NOT" | "-"] comparison}
> ```

From [Introduction](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters#introduction):

> To use advanced filters in the Logs Viewer, select the drop-down menu
>   at the end of the search bar, and choose [Convert to advanced
>   filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer#use_advanced_logs_filters). You see the advanced filter interface pictured below:
>
> [image]

In your case add the following line to the ones filled in by default when switching to the advanced filter:

```
NOT "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request."
```